# Is git-crypt or transcrypt more secure?

Tags: openssl, git

I'm looking at using either [git-crypt](https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt) or [transcrypt](https://github.com/elasticdog/transcrypt) to "transparently" encrypt a few secret files in a private github repository, using a symmetric key.

Separate from the debate of whether this should actually be done or not, **I am wondering if one of these tools appears to be notably more insecure or carry more concerning risk vs the other.**

Here's the primary security differences I've noticed:

*git-crypt*:

- is using c++ in combination with openssl c++ libraries to perform its functions and encryption/decryption at a lower level than transcrypt

  - This sounds like the kind of scenario where security vulnerabilities can be introduced by coding something incorrectly (as in some git-crypt code is incorrect, not the openssl library code), which seems to be where encryption products' weak points are (vs the underlying math actually being broken), but I don't have the expertise to evaluate the git-crypt code for this concern myself.
- is made of mostly 6-9 year old code at the time of this writing.

  - So is it possibly using old vulnerable openssl libraries or unfavored security algorithms?

*transcrypt*:

- is a bash script that simply calls openssl from the command line for all crypto-related things.

  - So if it's relying on openssl cli commands and doing much less "roll your own" crypto-related implementation, this sounds more secure, although I'm assuming some logic errors/vulnerabilities could still be introduced.
- is currently hard-coded to use MD5 in some capacity.

  - I don't understand what it's being used for, I just know that MD5 has not been in favor for a number of years, so this sounds like a negative thing, although I'm not sure how bad it is.
  - It's under active development to add support for PBKDF2 so maybe if they do that, this negative mark goes away.

Comment: Your understanding is not correct. Using library is namely the **opposite** of *"roll your own"*.